# application preserves the orientation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Which means an application preserves the orientation?
For example:

1) Linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ preserves orientation in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

2) $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ preserves orientation.

Comment: I'd guess it means they preserve angles

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orientation-Preserving.html